# What is the most "powerfull" method to prove a sequence is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

Given a sequence $a_n$ defined in a recursive manner, the methods I know to prove if the sequence is increasing are:

1) observe if $a_{n+1} - a_n > 0 \ \forall n.$

2) take $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and observe if it is $> 1$

3)procede by Induction.

4)take the first derivative (if possible) and see if it is always positive. Also check the starting  element of the sequence.

My questions are: If unsure about witch method to use first is there a hierarchy of usefullness (as happens with the root and ratio test for series) ?

Are there other methods to prove a sequence is increasing?

Is anyone of the one ones I mentioned redundant (if I tried one method it would be useless to try with an other specific method)?

Comment: part $2)$ also requires $\forall n$. They have almost the same meaning. If something is greater than the other either their rate is greater than $1$ or difference is greater than $0$. Derivative makes also the same job.

Comment: There is no such thing as the derivative of a sequence. There is a _difference_ sequence, which is what you are using in 1). Method 2) is only valid of all terms of your sequence are positive. Induction well generally not buy you much, in the sense that knowing $a_n$ to be greater than $a_{n-1}$ doesn't help in proving it is _less_ than $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: I could imagine in extreme cases a contradiction working. Also, if $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ then it is sufficient (but not necessary) that $f(x)>x$, and hence sufficient (but even weaker) that $f'(x)>1 \ \ \forall x$ and $f(a_0)>a_0$

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen If the sequence has a closed-form expression for $a_n$ that would make sense for non-integer input (e.g. any algebraic function), then differentiation makes sense, and would work if the expression is nice enough. If the derivative is positive (for all positive _real_ inputs, of course) then the sequence is increasing.